# Determining the force of a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, spring

How can I determine the maximum force a spring can release when it pops up? Is there even a formula for this?

Comment: Do you mean "force" or "energy"?  You say force, but the rest of the question seems to describe energy more than force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two equations that may be helpful to you, depending on exactly what you're trying to do with your spring:

Hooke's Law, which is written in equation form as $F=-k\Delta x$ states that the restoring force that returns a spring to equilibrium is proportional to its distance stretched, where $k$ is the spring constant.  The spring constant is a measure of how "stiff" or "stretchy" a particular spring is, and can be determined experimentally by applying a known force to a spring, and measuring how much is stretches or compresses.

So, if you know the spring constant of a spring, and you know how far it is displaced from equilibrium, you know the force the spring experts at that point.  Problem is, depending on what you want your spring to do, the force given by Hooke's Law is not necessarily the same *net force* that an object in contact with the spring would experience.  You would need to draw free body diagrams for both your spring and projectile, for example, if you wanted to spring-launch an object.

An alternative way to go is to look at the problem from an energy perspective.  The equation $PE_E=\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)^2$ describes the elastic potential energy within a spring that that is displaced some distance, $\Delta x$ from equilibrium.  Now, if you're using your spring to launch a projectile, you could set up a conservation of energy equation to determine the motion of your projectile.

Comment: Precisely what I was going to say.